# Do these TP4056 charging boards have built-in load sharing?

Tags: battery-charging, load, tp4056

I'm trying to design a simple rechargeable circuit that when plugged in, safely charges an 1S 18650 li-ion while also powering a load. I've been researching for awhile and can't seem to find consistency among the answers.

The datasheet says "The TP4056 automatically terminates the charge cycle when the charge current drops to 1/10th the programmed value after the final float voltage is reached. TP4056 Other features include current monitor, under voltage lockout, automatic recharge and two status pin to indicate charge termination and the presence of an input voltage."

But the forums claim that when plugged in, a current drawn by the load fools the TP4056 into thinking the current is charging the battery, and so current never drops below 1/10C--and overcharges the battery.

But maybe this is only a concern with the lone TP4056 IC and not [these charger boards](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B071RG4YWM). Do the additional components (DW01A and FS8205A) on these boards account for the load sharing hazard?

Comment: I use some little board found in power-banks ith IC like this one https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf/1256500/HOTCHIP/HT4928S/1

Comment: Questions about the functionality of an IC are now "consumer product use" questions. That's hilarious. 

Comment: Op even says ***I'm trying to design a simple rechargeable circuit***

Comment: Probably what you want to do is find a charger that supports "power path." I think "power path" is a TI marketing term but the basic idea is that the charger IC has a 5V input, a battery connection and a separate load connection. The load can be supplied either by the battery or by the 5V supply. The charger handles it automatically and charges the battery correctly even when a load is attached. Other vendors also make charger ICs like this. Maybe Nanjing Top Power even makes one, but I had trouble navigating their website due to my inability to read Chinese.

Answer (score 3):

No, the DW01 and accompanying FETs are just the cell protection circuit.

They don't do any load sharing, and so these boards don't handle a case where a load is drawing current while charging.

Comment: @Passerby Sure, it would, but because charger will never stops the charging under normal operation, it will always overcharge the battery until the last resort safety mechanism triggers. And that's not how anyone wants their devices designed.

Answer (score 1):

> But the forums claim that when plugged in, a current drawn by the load fools the TP4056 into thinking the current is charging the battery, and so current never drops below 1/10C--and overcharges the battery.

Yes, and no.

When you put a load on the electrical node where the IC output and Battery meet, the higher voltage source will provide the current up to where it can. This will be the TPs output which is at a higher voltage then the battery. So the IC has no way to tell the difference between the current going into the battery and the current going into the load.

The TP will continue to try to charge since it's cut off condition has not been met, a low current draw. The battery will continue to pull a current corresponding to the voltage/charge state compared to the fixed voltage at the shared node. It will eventually meet an equilibrium and stop and start and stop and start. It will never really turn off. Obviously this will depend on the battery charge/voltage and self discharge or how much if any current is pulled from the battery into the load. As the battery voltage reaches the chargers voltage the current drawn will continue to drop. **As long as it's not extensively left connected, then the small trickle charge is not too bad.** If left trickle charging for too long, you'll eventually get left with a bloated battery or worse.

Sidenote: this is why I normally disconnect the battery in Bluetooth speakers I leave plugged in to power all the time. The charge/discharge/charge cycle even with a proper charging IC will still end up blowing up the battery.

> Do the additional components (DW01A and FS8205A) on these boards account for the load sharing hazard?

Yes, but no. The DW01 will use the FS mosfets to cut off the battery when it sees a voltage above 4.45V. That is the overvoltage protection which is the same as overcharge protection. But in that situation the battery can't be used through the protection circuit until it self-discharges (or manually discharged). And once it does, the voltage present on the shared node will start to charge the battery again, as a trickle charge will do.

### In short

The TP4056 is not the "simple" charging circuit you want to implement if you have concerns about long term trickle charging ruining your battery with an active load. You could, with a few voltmeters and ammeters, prove this by setting it up and monitoring the behaviour, but the basic behaviour is easy enough to figure out. You will have to go with a more feature packed charging controller IC that can differentiate between battery and load.

Comment: Yes, Im just  discovering that such an ic might exist. Searching...

Comment: @JoshRuchty I discovered the same thing, and wrote a blog post about it ( https://www.thanassis.space/loadsharing.html ) on combining the TP4056 with a P-channel mosfet to get proper load sharing.